# Same column pointing to 2 different foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 3 models in Django:

1. Student
2. Teacher
3. Publication

A single publication can have multiple authors, who can be both students and teachers. Since a student and teacher can have multiple publications and a publication can have multiple teachers and students as authors, I am using a M2M relationship using a through table called PublicationAuthor. However, I am not sure how to get my authors column in my through table. My effort so far :

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publication = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, through=PublicationAuthor, related_name='students')

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publication = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, through=PublicationAuthor, related_name='students')
    
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class PublicationAuthor(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    authors =
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_authors = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='student_authros')
    teacher_authors = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher, related_name='teacher_authors')
```

So that if the `publication` has no `author` of some type the field simply remains empty.

Comment: how do I do this with the intermediate table since I need to capture some more information using the through table